# Matching AWS Lambda invocations to Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

For a given AWS Lambda invocation, I can recover various identifiers for it, like its `RequestID`, or its X-Ray tracing header.

Using the CLI, I can see details of the Cloudwatch log streams via `aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/my_func_name'`.

Each Lambda invocation seems to generate a log stream, but I can't see a straightforward way to match Lambda invocations against these log streams. Neither the `RequestID` nor the X-Ray tracing header seem to be part of the log stream. I could simply invoke the function and then assume that the latest log stream is the one corresponding to that function, but that does not feel at all robust.

Any help appreciated.